# How to restore Windows XP boot record?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, boot

Firstly I installed Windows XP, secondly Linux Ubuntu. Grub erased Windows boot record. How to restore Windows XP boot record? Which command to use?

Comment: Do you want a dual boot system? or you want only windows xp?

Comment: YES, i want to install windows boot record ant then by manual install GRUB, which supports windows boot record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot with your windows CD into the recovery console. Issue `fixmbr`. Reboot. There you go.

Answer (score 2):

Under Ubuntu there are two tools (that I know about) to install windows master boot record. First is `mbr`. You can install it with `sudo apt-get install mbr` . The second and in my opinion superior is [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/#Download).
But you need to compile it. Simply download, unpack, and install with `sudo make install` (reading README wouldn't hurt also). Then type `ms-sys --help` to choose your mbr type.

For Windows XP it is

```
sudo ms-sys --mbr /dev/your_device
```

and for Windows 7:

```
 sudo ms-sys --mbr7 /dev/your_device
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a chainload without installing the windows first stage boot loader into the mbr. Take a look at [this](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_4.html) for further information.